# HAProxy with https backend and SNI

Tags: haproxy

Please tell me how to implement a request to the backend server proxy https on port 8443. My configuration doesn't work. I'm getting error 503. Requests to http backend are successful.

```
frontend https_frontend
bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/haproxyssl.pem
mode http

tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Ssl on if { ssl_fc }
redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
use_backend bk_webserver if { ssl_fc_sni webserver.name.com }

backend bk_wscucu
server webserver.name.local 192.168.1.10:8443 check
```

Comment: Please capture the log entry from HAProxy for a failed request.  You have kind of a jumble of configuration settings, here, as if you were sort of attempting to do Layer 4 pass-through of SSL to the back-end, but your front-end is configured to terminate SSL and operate at Layer 7.  Much of the config here has no effect.

Comment: use "server webserver.name.local 192.168.1.10:8443 check ssl" if your certificate at the endpoint is self-signed use this  "server webserver.name.local 192.168.1.10:8443 check ssl verify none"